# How to change the language based on store - android

Tags: android, google-play

In an android app which supports multiple language, if I launch in play store,

1. Does the app changes to the language of the country downloaded by the user and without changing by user manually?
2. Can we change the language based on any web service? (Back end admin panel). If the admin choose Spanish the language should change accordingly.
3. If string localization is only way, How I can change the dynamic values retrieved from web services?

**Note:** I have done String Localization in the app.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the app changes to the language of the country downloaded by the
>   user and without changing by user manually?

Application language is based on User's phone language. If a user has French as default language then your application will look for locale string file in value-fr. Let's say user's default language on phone is Chinese and you don't provide locale file for Chinese then it will fall back to default locale in values folder.

> Can we change the language based on any web service? (Back end admin
>   panel). If the admin choose Spanish the language should change
>   accordingly.

Yes, you can force a specific locale yourself in the app. ([Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android))

> If string localization is only way, How I can change the dynamic
>   values retrieved from web services?

First you check in the application what is user's default language, then when calling web service that returns dynamic values pass language identifier (like en, fr etc). Now in your service now you can return dynamic values in user's default language.

Comment: For the first question,I meant to, say chinese user sets default language in his mobile as english but when he downloads the app from chinese play store, is there a way to show the app information as in chinese. hope you got my question now.

Comment: If a user has set default language English even living in China then Play Store will also show your application information in English. If user sets a language as default then user's gonna get that language whenever possible unless within your app you override that.